# Sharepoint: OpenSearch common forms/cookie authentication

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, opensearch

I have an OpenSearch provider that I am trying to integrate with Sharepoint (Online). This provider is protected by authentication.

Sharepoint supports Cookie or Form authentication for OpenSearch. When I give a url with login page and click Enter Credentials it shows my page, I enter my credentials and it shows popup asking if authentication was successful. I clicked yes and then it gives the following error:

"An error occurred when communicating with the remote server. This may be because the URL provided was malformed or the site might be unavailable or it could not be reached within the specified timeout or the proxy settings are not configured."

I have tried multiple sites, including for example google:
https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?hl=fr&continue=https://www.google.fr/%3Fgfe_rd%3Dcr%26ei%3D9j-lVdXLMYXF8AesrK-4Dg%26gws_rd%3Dssl#identifier

Do you know if there are some required configuration on the site?